# Duplicate one column and do some calculation to add this in a new columns

Tags: awk

I have a table like this

```
ZRSR2_10A_F_P5,18,chrX,15822707,15822993,287,chrX
ZRSR2_10B_F_P5,18,chrX,15822876,15823101,226,chrX
ZRSR2_10C_F_02_P5,22,chrX,15823055,15823310,256,chrX
```

and I need this

```
ZRSR2_10A_F_P5,18,chrX,15822707,15822993,287,chrX,15822707,15822725
ZRSR2_10B_F_P5,18,chrX,15822876,15823101,226,chrX,15822876,15822894
ZRSR2_10C_F_02_P5,22,chrX,15823055,15823310,256,chrX,15823055,15823077
```

I am trying this

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $0,$4,$4+$2}'
```

But I am getting this

```
,15822707,15822725chrX,15822707,15822993,287,chrX
,15822876,15822894chrX,15822876,15823101,226,chrX
,15823055,1582307722,chrX,15823055,15823310,256,chrX
```

Why am I getting these results? I thought that  -F,: Set the input field separator to a comma.
-v OFS=,: Set the output field separator to a comma.
{print $0,$4,$4+$2}: Print the entire original line ($0), followed by the value in column 4, and then the sum of column 4 and column 2.

Comment: You got CRLF line endings in your input file

Comment: With a CRLF-free input file, I get the expected output. With CRLF line endings, I get the result you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip the carriage-return?

```bash
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{sub(/\r$/,""); print $0,$4,$4+$2}'
```